# UIPickerView: unrecognized selector sent to instance - only on ios 3.1.x

Tags: iphone, crash, uipickerview, unrecognized-selector

I have a UIViewController that has a UIPickerView. The picker's datasource and delegate are my controller as you would expect.

My controller implements the `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocols and all the methods that are required:
`numberOfComponentsInPickerView`, `numberOfRowsInComponent`, `titleForRow` and `didSelectRow`

It's all working well on ios 4 but crashes on 3.1 with a nice `"unrecognized selector sent to instance"` as soon as I call `[picker reloadInputViews]` (It doesn't even reach breakpoints in the delegate or datasource methods).

I can't see what's missing here (happy to post code is needed)

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: usually it tells you what object and what selector you used in the line with "unrecognized selector sent to instance". Please post this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `[picker reloadAllComponents]`. `reloadInputViews` is a method of `UIResponder` and only available since iOS 3.2. At least according to the documentation. Which you should read.

Comment: Spot on thanks! 

On a side note I did read the doc (thanks for the lecture) but still couldn't find the issue. Have you considered that if everyone knew all "the documentation" then you wouldn't need stackoverflow? I do think it's often quicker to google a problem for an answer than read boring doc. Plus that got you 25 point ;-)

Comment: Well.. I plugged "reloadInputViews" into the mythical google and presto, a page came out on top saying "since 3.2". But I must admit iOS docs can be a pain to comprehend. Anyway good you solved it, that's what we're here for ;-)